# Выполнение задания из учебника Python

Tags: python

Возникла проблема с заданием в учебнике. Задание написано так:
Кинотеатр установил несколько вариантов цены на билеты в зависимости от возраста посетителя. Для посетителей младше 3 лет билет бесплатный; в возрасте от 3 до 12 билет стоит $10; наконец,если возраст посетителя больше 12, билет стоит 15$.
Напишите цикл, который предлагает пользователю ввести возраст и выводит цену билета. ДОП ЗАДАНИЕ:
Выход из цикла по команде break, если пользователь вводит значение 'quit'

Собственно условия в цикле написаны, не могу понять как сравнить со значением 'quit' вот код

```
age = "How old are you?"
age += "\nEnter 'quit' to exit: "
while True:
    message = input(age)
    age1 = int(input(age))
    if message == 'quit':
        break
    elif age1 <= 3:
        print("Cinema is free")
    elif age1 <= 12:
        print("Cinema cost's 10$")
    else:
        print("Cinema cost's 15$")
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправленная версия программы

```py
age = "How old are you?"
age += "\nEnter 'quit' to exit: "
while True:
    # возраст уже ввели в message, не нужно его спрашивать для age1 ещё раз
    message = input(age)
    # но перед тем, как перевести message в age1, проверим, не ввели ли quit
    # если сначала попробовать перенести значение в age1, будет вызвано исключение, в результате попытки использовать оператор int('quit') 
    if message == 'quit':
        break
    age1 = int(message)
    if age1 <= 3:
        print("Cinema is free")
    elif age1 <= 12:
        print("Cinema cost's 10$")
    else:
        print("Cinema cost's 15$")
```

Результат работы программы:

```
How old are you?
Enter 'quit' to exit: 5
Cinema cost's 10$
How old are you?
Enter 'quit' to exit: 5
Cinema cost's 10$
How old are you?
Enter 'quit' to exit: 3
Cinema is free
How old are you?
Enter 'quit' to exit: 15
Cinema cost's 15$
How old are you?
Enter 'quit' to exit: quit
```

Comment: О боже, я настолько туп, что не догадался... Спасибо большое...

Comment: @R3LLY не за что. Если ответ решает вашу задачу, вы можете поставить возле него галочку, чтобы другие участники сообщества знали, что вопрос уже решён

Answer (score 2):

В *Python* с версии 3.8 появился [моржовый (walrus) оператор](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/555924/). С ним можно сделать более удобную проверку на выход из цикла. В таком случае решение будет более лаконичным и выглядеть вот так:

```py
prompt = "How old are you?\n" \
         "Enter 'quit' to exit: "
while (message := input(prompt)) != "quit":
    age = int(message)
    if age <= 3:
        print("Cinema is free")
    elif age <= 12:
        print("Cinema cost's 10$")
    else:
        print("Cinema cost's 15$")
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас пересекаются условия `age <= 3` и `age <= 12` (второе включает в себя первое). Плюс не понятно зачем вам второе `break` вконце цикла, который срабатывает всегда, независимо от ввода

```
age = "How old are you?"
age += "\nEnter 'quit' to exit: "
while True:
    message = input(age)
    if message == 'quit':
        break
    elif int(message) <= 3:
        print("Cinema is free")
    elif 3 < int(message) <= 12:
        print("Cinema cost's 10$")
    else:
        print("Cinema cost's 15$")
```

Comment: Все равно сообщение правильное выводится, даже если age<=3 и age <=12

Comment: whizz169, оператор `elif` уже подразумевает, что условия выше не выполнены. Т.е. если условие `<= 3` выполнено, до этого оператора дело даже не дойдёт. Потому проверять ещё раз условие, которое уже было проверено выше, смысла нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Билет в зоопарк
    years = input("Введите возраст посетителя: ")
    const=0
    while True:
        if 3 < int(years) <=12:
            print("14$")
            const+=14
        elif 13 < int(years) <=65:
            print("23$")
            const+=23
        elif int(years) > 65:
            print("18$")
            const+=18
        else:
           print("вход свободный")
        years = input("Введите возраст посетителя: ")
        print('Если всё, нажмите q')
        if years =='q':
                break`
    print("Общая стоимость: $", format(const, '.2f'), sep='')
```

Comment: Этот код на других числах / значениях работает, отличных от вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Это задание решил такой конструкцией.

```
message = 'Hello! Please tell me your age: '

while message:
    age = input(message)
    if age == 'q':
        break
    elif int(age) < 3:
        print("For you the ticket costs free")
    elif (int(age) >= 3) and (int(age) < 12):
        print("Your ticket costs: $10")
    elif int(age) >= 12:
        print("Your ticket costs: 15$")
```

**Вывод:**

```
Hello! Please tell me your age: 1
For you the ticket costs free
Hello! Please tell me your age: 5
Your ticket costs: $10
Hello! Please tell me your age: 19
Your ticket costs: 15$
Hello! Please tell me your age:
```

Comment: age лучше один раз привести к int. В последней ветке вместо elif достаточно else

Comment: Да, с else проглядел спасибо. Я приводил age изначально к int, но цикл входил в бесконечность, а с строками выходила бы ошибка.