# Завершение цикла строковым значением

Tags: python, int

такая задача, нужно чтоб при введении слово 'quit' завершался цикл. Как задать в условии значение age строковым, если в начале цикла оно уже переведено в числовое?

```
    active = True
    while active:
        age = input("Hello, please indicate your age: ")
        age = int(age)
        q = 'quit'
        if age < 3:
            print("The ticket is free for you:)")
        if age >= 3 and age < 12:
            print("Please pay 10$")
        if age > 12:
            print("Please pay 15$")
        if age == 'quit':
            active = False
```

Comment: Зачем нужна переменная `q`, если она нигде не используется?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Выполнение задания из учебника Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058932/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-python)

Comment: переменная q попала туда случайно, вроде бы удалил когда вставлял код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто перенесите условие выхода из цикла в начало, перед присвоения переменной `age` типа `int`

```
while True:
    age = input("Hello, please indicate your age: ")
    if age == 'quit':
        break      # выходим из цикла, если ввели 'quit'
    age = int(age)
    q = 'quit'
    if age < 3:
        print("The ticket is free for you:)")
    if age >= 3 and age < 12:
        print("Please pay 10$")
    if age > 12:
        print("Please pay 15$")
```

Comment: _`q = 'quit'`_ - вроде это лишнее?

Comment: Не додумался)) спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить
`if age == 'quit':
    active = False`
На:
`if age == 'quit':
    break`
Вот готовый код:

```
while active:
    age = input("Hello, please indicate your age: ")
    if age == 'quit':
        break
    age=int(age)
    if age < 3:
        print("The ticket is free for you:)")
    if age >= 3 and int(age) < 12:
        print("Please pay 10$")
    if age > 12:
        print("Please pay 15$")
```

Comment: Не проще ли один раз выполнить `age = int(age)` в строке после `break`, чем в каждом `if`?

Comment: _`q = 'quit'`_ - вроде это лишнее?

Comment: этот способ я знаю, но должен был быть вариант по проще. Спасибо.

Comment: @Akina да так проще)

Comment: @Qwertiy точно,лишнее